# Free and projective modules

Tags: modules, projective-module

I have two simple questions. Let $R$ be a ring. Is every free $R$-Mod of the form $R^{(S)}$ for some set $S$? Can $R^S$ be projective for an infinite set $S$, for suitable, non-trivial $R$? Note that in the second question there are no $(,)$ around $S$.

Comment: What definition of free module do you have? Most definitions make your first question immediate!

Comment: We can take a basis for $S$, right? I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: If $R$ is a field, then $R^S$ is free for all $S$,simply because all $R$-modules are free in that case. You can take more generally $R$ to be any semisimple ring, like $M_n(\mathbb R)$; in this case all modules are projective.